Path difference between RVIZ-request and C++-Interface
I'm working with a UR10 and could setup MoveIt2 with the wizard and can move it around in RVIZ with the MotionPlanning plugin. Collisions work (I have a small camera on the gripper) and planning/executing produces good, short paths.
Now I want to use the C++-interface and started with the Hello World demo. This also works somehow, but the paths are immensely complex:

I use the same planning group as in RVIZ, but the planner just can't find the trivial transition. This is my debug output:
[moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.909064 seconds
[moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'ur10'...
[moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[moveit_ros.robot_model_loader]: No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml!
[move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm_planning_group.
[moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group_interface_tutorial.remote_control]: RemoteControl Ready.
[move_group_demo]: Planning frame: world
[move_group_demo]: End effector link: gripper_center
[move_group_demo]: Available Planning Groups:
[move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready

The kinematics.yaml in my moveit_config-package exists and has this content:
arm_planning_group:
  kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.0050000000000000001
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.0050000000000000001

I'm a bit running out of ideas, any proposals on what I could try next?
